# Gitlab ci - pipeline which triggers pipeline in another project, does not finish

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a gitlab ci which triggers a pipeline in another repository.

That pipeline does finish, but it does not cause the original pipeline to finish as well.
This worked up until a few days ago, we did not change anything in our gitlab ci's for both main repository and tests repository.

[image: main repository pipeline - still running]

[image: triggered pipeline in another repository already finished]

This is how the tests pipeline is triggered:

```
trigger_integration_test:
extends:
    - .merge_request_rules
stage: test_on_dev
variables:
    TEST_TYPE: ci
trigger:
    project: <path to>/backend-inregration-tests-repository
    strategy: depend
```

Gitlab version is `GitLab Enterprise Edition 14.1.0-pre e230eeca384`

Please advise on how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The manual step at the end of the pipeline was preventing the main pipeline from finishing.
Once disabled it, everything returned back to normal.